# Swift: accessing computed property through pointer

Tags: swift

I was playing around with trying to get/set a computed property of an object through a pointer to that property. I've included the code snippet and output below.

The gist of the snippet is that there's a class `Foo` with a computed property `bar`. The `Mutator` class keeps a pointer and has a computed property `value` that just gets/sets the value it points to. So, if I create `f1: Foo` and then a `m1: Mutator` object that references that `f1.bar`, I would think that setting `m1.value` would also set `f1.bar1`. It works sometimes, but not always.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Class definitions

class Foo
{
    private var data = [String: Double]()

    var bar: Double? 
    {
        get { return self.data["bar"] }
        set { self.data["bar"] = newValue }
    }       

    init(_ key: String, _ val: Double)
    {
        self.data[key] = val
    }
}

class Mutator
{
    let name: String
    let storage: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double?>

    var value: Double?
    {
        get { return self.storage.pointee }
        set { self.storage.pointee = newValue}
    }

    init(name: String, storage: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double?>)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.storage = storage
    }

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create and display mutators directly

print("-\nCreate and display mutator directly")

let f1 = Foo("bar", 1.1)
let f2 = Foo("bar", 2.2)
let f3 = Foo("bar", 3.3)

let m1 = Mutator(name:"mf1", storage: &f1.bar) // Or, let m1 = Mutator(name:"f1", storage: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double?>(&f1.bar))
let m2 = Mutator(name:"mf2", storage: &f2.bar)
let m3 = Mutator(name:"mf3", storage: &f3.bar)

var before = m1.value
m1.value = 199.1
var after = m1.value
print("\(m1.name): before=\(before), after=\(after) @ \(m1.storage)")   

before = m2.value
m2.value = 299.2
after = m2.value
print("\(m2.name): before=\(before), after=\(after) @ \(m2.storage)")

before = m3.value
m3.value = 299.2
after = m3.value
print("\(m3.name): before=\(before), after=\(after) @ \(m3.storage)")

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create mutators inside function

func createMutators() -> [Mutator]
{   
    print("-\nIn createMutators function ...")

    let m1 = Mutator(name:"mf1", storage: &f1.bar)
    let m2 = Mutator(name:"mf2", storage: &f2.bar)  
    let m3 = Mutator(name:"mf3", storage: &f3.bar)

    print("\(m1.name)=\(m1.value) @ \(m1.storage)")
    print("\(m2.name)=\(m2.value) @ \(m2.storage)")
    print("\(m3.name)=\(m3.value) @ \(m3.storage)")

    return [m1, m2, m3] 
}

let mutator = createMutators()

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Display mutators returned by function

print("-\nDisplay mutator returned by function")
for m in mutator
{
    let before = m.value
    m.value = 10.0 + (before ?? Double.nan)
    let after = m.value

    print("\(m.name): before=\(before), after=\(after) @ \(m.storage)") 
}
```

If I run the above code on Linux, I get the following output:

```
Create and display mutator directly
mf1: before=Optional(1.1000000000000001), after=Optional(199.09999999999999) @ 0x00007ffd38f82730
mf2: before=Optional(2.2000000000000002), after=Optional(299.19999999999999) @ 0x00007ffd38f82708
mf3: before=Optional(3.2999999999999998), after=Optional(299.19999999999999) @ 0x00007ffd38f826e0
-
In createMutators function ...
mf1=Optional(1.1000000000000001) @ 0x00007ffd38f82288
mf2=Optional(2.2000000000000002) @ 0x00007ffd38f82260
mf3=Optional(3.2999999999999998) @ 0x00007ffd38f82238
-
Display mutator returned by function
mf1: before=Optional(4.9406564584124654e-324), after=Optional(10.0) @ 0x00007ffd38f82288
mf2: before=Optional(6.9527664311957093e-310), after=Optional(10.0) @ 0x00007ffd38f82260
mf3: before=nil, after=Optional(nan) @ 0x00007ffd38f82238
```

The first output block shows expected behavior. The second block points to a different address, which is unexpected. Weirder still is that despite having the wrong address, it reads the correct values. The last output block has the same address as in the second block, but reads different initial values, though it does manage to set and read back the values correctly.

I know this is perhaps an abuse of the computed properties and pointers. But can anyone explain why it works sometimes? Why does creating it in the function give it a different address? Why would reading it in the function and after it's returned give different answers when the addresses are the same? Is there a way to make this work?

Just to confuse things further: the above was from running on Linux. When I try this experiment on a mac I get somewhat different results, though the overall observation that sometimes it works remains true.

Comment: That's the Unsafe in UnsafeMutablePointer. :)

Comment: It's difficult to see in what context you would want to do, essentially "performance programming" in anything involving the Swift / iOS milieu. If this is hobbyism (which is great), (go for it)[http://opencores.org]!  :)  As hotpaw explains, even in Swift you can very much grab a slab of ram memory and muck about with it yourself - that perhaps is the path you are taking?  Enjoy.

Comment: Yep, just playing around and experimenting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of this is defined behaviour. It may or may not produce expected results, or it may just crash at runtime.

When you say

```
let m1 = Mutator(name:"mf1", storage: &f1.bar)
```

Swift will allocate some memory and initialise it to the value returned by `f1.bar`'s getter. A pointer to this memory will then be passed into `Mutator`'s `init` – and after the call, Swift will then call `f1.bar`'s setter with the (possibly changed) contents of the memory it allocated.

This memory will then be deallocated – the pointer is now no longer valid. Reading and writing to its `pointee` will produce *undefined behaviour*. Therefore, you should *not* persist the pointer after the call to `Mutator`'s initialiser.

One way in order to get the behaviour you want is to use two closures for the getting and setting of `f1.bar`, both *capturing* `f1`. This ensures that the reference to `f1` remains valid as long as the closures live.

For example:

```
struct Mutator<T> {

    let getter: () -> T
    let setter: (T) -> Void

    var value: T {
        get {
            return getter()
        }
        nonmutating set {
            setter(newValue)
        }
    }

    init(getter: @escaping () -> T, setter: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
        self.getter = getter
        self.setter = setter
    }
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
class Foo {
    private var data = [String : Double]()

    var bar: Double? {
        get { return self.data["bar"] }
        set { self.data["bar"] = newValue }
    }

    init(_ key: String, _ val: Double) {
        self.data[key] = val
    }
}


let f1 = Foo("bar", 1.1)
let m1 = Mutator(getter: { f1.bar }, setter: { f1.bar = $0 })

let before = m1.value
m1.value = 199.1

print("m1: before = \(before as Optional), after = \(m1.value as Optional)")
print("f1 after = \(f1.bar as Optional)")

// m1: before = Optional(1.1000000000000001), after = Optional(199.09999999999999)
// f1 after = Optional(199.09999999999999)
```

Although one downside to this approach is the repetition of value you're getting and setting (`f1.bar` in this case). One alternative implementation would be to use a single closure with a function argument that takes an `inout` parameter, returning the (possibly mutated) value.

```
struct Mutator<T> {

    let getter: () -> T
    let setter: (T) -> Void

    var value: T {
        get {
            return getter()
        }
        nonmutating set {
            setter(newValue)
        }
    }

    init(mutator: @escaping ((inout T) -> T) -> T) {

        // a function, which when applied, will call mutator with a function input
        // that just returns the inout argument passed by the caller.
        getter = {
            mutator { $0 }
        }

        // a function, which when applied with a given new value, will call mutator
        // with a function that will set the inout argument passed by the caller
        // to the new value, which will then be returned 
        // (but ignored by the outer function)
        setter = { newValue in
            _ = mutator { $0 = newValue; return $0 }
        }
    }
}

// ...

let f1 = Foo("bar", 1.1)
let m1 = Mutator { $0(&f1.bar) }
```

The getter now simply applies the passed function, returning the `inout` parameter passed (`f1.bar` in this case), and the setter uses this `inout` parameter in order to assign a new value.

Although personally, I prefer the first approach, despite the repetition.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! My original implementation was very similar to your first suggestion; the pointer approach was just to experiment with Swift pointers. The second implementation is an interesting one I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

The Swift language definition does not require it to not move (or reuse) the memory used by class object instance properties, once outside the block or scope where unsafe pointers and other internal references are valid.

So, in your second and third case, the object (or some of its properties) has likely been moved and you are examining and (dangerously) changing memory where the object used to be, and where part of some completely different type of object might currently be, through a stale (and thus very unsafe) pointer.

So the Swift compiler (which knows when and where it moved stuff) knows how to read and write the property inside the instance.  But you (via stale pointers) do not.

Added: If you want to do this type of stuff, then allocate (and manage) the memory yourself (which **is** possible in Swift).