# Store reference to struct in Swift

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a model, called `Car` with a property `color` of type `String`:

```
class Car {
    var color: String?
}
```

Now, I have another class called `Interface` that I wish to use to modify the value of the `color` property of `Car`. To do this, I'd like to somehow bind `color` to a property of `Interface`, such as `key`:

```
class Interface {

    var storedKey: String?

    func bind(key: String?) {
        self.storedKey = key
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let corolla = Car()
corolla.color = "green"
let interface = Interface()
interface.bind(key: &corolla.color)
interface.storedKey = "blue"
print(corolla.color) // still "green"! :(
```

This approach fails because strings are value types (structs) in Swift, so the `bind` function gets a copy of `corolla.color`, not a reference. This means modifying `storedKey` of `interface` has no effect on the value of `corolla.color`.

If we add `inout` to the binding function as shown below, we basically obtain a reference to the key passed in ([it's actually copied in then copied out](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545)), but it only lasts for the scope of the function.

```
func bind(key: inout String?) {
    self.storedKey = key  // assignment of value type is a copy! :/
}
```

The results are the same, modifying `storedKey` has no effect on the property it is bound to.

**What this boils down to is, can we obtain a reference to a struct in Swift?**

---

Since structs occupy space in memory, we may be able to obtain a pointer to the key passed in, here is a working (incorrect) solution:

```
class Car {
    var color: String?
}

let corolla = Car()
corolla.color = "green"

class Interface {

    var storedKey: UnsafeMutablePointer<String?>?

    func bind(_ key: inout String?) {
        self.storedKey = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &key) { ptr in
            return ptr
        }
    }
}

var interface = Interface()
interface.bind(&corolla.color)
interface.storedKey?.pointee = "blue" // :O it's... working?
print(corolla.color)
```

As I see it, this breaks at least two semantic rules in Swift:

1. `withUnsafeMutablePointer` converts the address of an instance passed in via `&` to a `UnsafeMutablePointer` of that instances' type, to be used **only within** the provided closure. As per [the Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2429788-withunsafemutablepointer):

   > The pointer argument to body is valid only for the lifetime of the closure. Do not escape it from the closure for later use.
2. The second problem is that this takes advantage of a Swift compiler optimization that allows `bind` to actually obtain a reference to `key` instead of a copy. Otherwise, the pointer would not obtain a reference to the original key, but to a copy. `inout` parameters are normally implemented using a behavior known as copy-in copy-out, whereby a copy of the argument is passed in to the function, possibly modified, and then assigned back to the original argument. [As per the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351), there is an optimization whereby if the argument is a stored property, the same memory location is used both inside and outside the function body. This allowed our pointer to obtain a reference to the original String struct instead of a copy, allowing this to work.

   > As an optimization, when the argument is a value stored at a physical address in memory, the same memory location is used both inside and outside the function body.

Is there any way to store a reference to a struct such as `String`? Or am I on a wild goose chase?

Edit 1: Also, I have no control of the types of `Car`'s properties.

Comment: Compare [Swift: accessing computed property through pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42798354/2976878) – you may just want a closure.

Comment: You may be looking for "Lenses": http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/lenses-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a reference to your struct as you already researched.

What you can do is use a Box class and pass that around.

Then you would use the Box everywhere and access its struct property wherever needed.

Something like:

```
class Box<T> {
   var value: T
   init(value: T) {
      self.value = value
   }
}
```

and use it with a Car

```
let boxedCar = Box(value: Car(...))
```

You can share references to this box and always access the car through the value property

Comment: I'd seen this approach but it doesn't work because writing to the `value` property of the box class has no effect on the `String` it's bound to, because the assignment `self.value = value` is a copy.

Comment: You're boxing the `Car` which is already a class. I'd thought of boxing the car's properties, but I have no control of the types of `Car`'s properties (I'll edit the question to reflect this).

Comment: If you always access the car via the box, then modifying the struct (and thereby just setting a new one as the property) will be visible to everyone accessing it via the box wouldn't it?

Comment: Your Interface needs a reference to the Box then of course