# Swift Use UnsafeMutablePointer of Struct to get value of String Error

Tags: swift, unsafemutablepointer

I want to get the pointer of a struct, and get or set the value. the code is here

```
protocol TestProtocol {

}

struct TestStruct: TestProtocol {
    var username: String?
}

class TestViewModel {
    var testStruct: TestProtocol?

    func test() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<TestStruct?>? {
        guard let _ = self.testStruct as? TestStruct else {
            return nil
        }
        return withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &(self.testStruct)) { (pointer) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<TestStruct?> in
            return pointer.withMemoryRebound(to: TestStruct?.self, capacity: MemoryLayout<TestStruct?>.size) { (point) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<TestStruct?> in
                return point
            }
        }
    }
}

func getvalue() {
     let testViewModel = TestViewModel()
     var testStruct = TestStruct()
     testStruct.username = "123"
     testViewModel.testStruct = testStruct
     print("\(testViewModel.test()?.pointee?.username)")
     // here print Optional("")， why not "123"?
}
```

the get value function print result is wrong, but if the TestStruct only has a var of Int, the result is right. just like that:

```
struct TestStruct: TestProtocol {
        var number: Int?
    }

func getvalue() {
         let testViewModel = TestViewModel()
         var testStruct = TestStruct()
         testStruct. number = 123
         testViewModel.testStruct = testStruct
         print("\(testViewModel.test()?.pointee?.username)")
         // Optional(123)
    }
```

why? how to fix it?

Comment: This is all undefined behaviour – the pointer arguments in the closures passed to `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to:)` & `.withMemoryRebound(to:)` are only valid for the lifetime of those calls. Also directly re-interpreting the memory of an instance of `TestProtocol?` as `TestStruct?` is doomed to fail (it *might* appear to "work" in some cases, like in your case with `Int` – but that's really just based on implementation details and still undefined behaviour). What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @Hamish In the class TestViewModel has a var testStruct of TestProtocol?, but I pass a TestStruct instance testStruct to it, it's Value reference, I want to cast it to TestStruct and set value to itself, not the copy value of the it . Could u understand? My English is pool

Comment: @Hamish could u help me? thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand the exact problem you're trying to solve – if you want reference semantics, you should use a class, or maybe even a closure (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/42798354/2976878).

Answer (score 1):

here's the pattern for making/using/finishing with a pointer to an object:

```
// this allocates memory for the pointer
let somePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<someType>.allocate(capacity: 1)
// this initializes the memory to the value
somePointer.initialize(to: someInstanceOfSomeTime)
// this allows me to access the object
somePointer.pointee.someMethod(/* ... */)
// this destroys the memory
somePointer.deinitialize(count: 1)
somePointer.deallocate(capacity: 1)
```

Since your memory may contain a type that either directly or indirectly contains a reference counted type, it is vital that you understand that pointers have state and you need to manage the lifetime of all those states.

This is your typical lifetime
 - A pointer is allocated but its contents is not initialized and must not be used
 - A pointer is initialized and its contents may now be used
 - A pointer is deinitialized and now it's contents may no longer may be used but you can initialize it again
 - A pointer is deallocated and may no longer be initialized.

Knowing these steps is really important. When you're working with typical swift code you are doing all of these steps but they are implicit. Take this simple example:

```
public func printThingValue(t:Thing) {
    let aCopy = t.value
    print(aCopy)
}
```

Let's consider the lifetime of aCopy. Before calling, aCopy is not allocated. When you enter the function, aCopy is allocated (on the stack) but not initialized. When the assignment happens, aCopy is initialized. When print is called, aCopy is used. Before `printThingValue` exits, aCopy is deinitialized. When it exits, aCopy gets deallocated (stack frame destroyed).

Knowing this lifetime is very important because this is *exactly* the model that is used by pointers but it is no longer automatic/implicit.

Related to this is the answer to the question: can I construct a value type that is not initialized? The answer is yes - there is a way and that's through `UnsafeMutablePointer`. If you call `allocate` you will get uninitialized memory that represents your value type, but this is extremely dangerous. If you assign to the `pointee` before it has been initialized, you require the swift compiler to inject code that will destroy the value that's there. And this will either crash or result in undefined behavior if the type pointed to contains a reference type.

Knowing and managing these steps is the way that Apple has tried to make it possible for you to use pointers, but it creates a new set of dangers:

```
- using an unallocated pointer (crash)
- using/assigning to an allocated but uninitialized pointer (crash)
- failing to deinitialize an initialized pointer (reference leak)
- failing to deallocate a deinitialized pointer (memory leak)
```